# Searching not working on 2nd page with ngx-pagination

Tags: typescript, angular8, ngx-pagination

I have used pagination after search filter, still not working. 1st page the search filter working properly but other page it's not working.I have used ngx-pagination and for search have written searching pipe. My code-
[image]

Comment: Looks like you forgot to actually include your code

Comment: I have attached the screen shot of my code, plz look and help.